# Assigning a possibly null property to a variable without having to access property twice

Tags: c#, null

I am assigning a property value to a property however the property value may be null and I need to accommodate for this, currently I handle this in the following way:

```
int position;
if (record.Number != null) position = record.Number;
```

Is there a way of performing the same action without having to call the object twice? Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `record.Number` in this case? Unless there's some implicit conversion from that type to `int`, your code wouldn't work anyway. It would help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: What if `record.Number` *is* null? Is there a default value you'd like to assign to `position`?

Comment: record.Number is of type decimal?. No I would not like to assign a default value, just a return/continue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a default value for `position`, you can use the null-coalescing operator or [`Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d6d4f1d.aspx)

```
int position = record.Number ?? defaultValue;
//or
int position = record.Number.GetValueOrDefault(defaultValue);
```

Otherwise, if `position` already *has* a value, you can use `position` as the right-hand side operand to leave it the way it is.

```
int position = record.Number ?? position;
//or
int position = record.Number.GetValueOrDefault(position);
```

Comment: There are [specific methods for both of these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58x571cw.aspx).

Comment: @Rawling Though I personally find the null-coalescing operator more readable, you make a good point, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nullable int

```
int? position = record.Number;
```

Then check `position == null` or `position.HasValue` when you need to use it's value..